# What's with all of the requests for /js/jsdiff.min.js?

Tags: discussion

I was checking the access log for one of my websites (http://files.quickmediasolutions.com) and came across literally **tens of thousands** of requests for the file `/js/jsdiff.min.js` (which existed at some point in the past but no longer does). This accounts for 99.7% of all requests to my website.

What makes this strange is the referrers:

- `http://unix.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits`
- `http://unix.stackexchange.com/review/late-answers`
- `http://unix.stackexchange.com/review/close`
- `http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/98871/how-do-i-display-contents-of-a-file-where-path-environment-chances-are-made`
- `http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11343/linux-tools-to-treat-files-as-sets-and-perform-set-operations-on-them/11667`
- `http://unix.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=comm`

(This list is not inclusive, by any means.)

Does anyone know anything about this? As you can imagine, this is eating up a fair bit of server resources (namely disk space for the access logs). I wondered if perhaps someone has a UserScript installed that is hotlinking to the file?

Answer (score 7):

I think I know the issue. I noticed that if you're using the Stack Exchange Post Editor that when I enable it I start seeing traffic to your domain when using `iftop`:

```
$ sudo iftop -i wlan0
greeneggs.local                                  => quickmediasolutions.com                              4.32Kb   885b    221b
```

When I disable this extension the traffic stops. I believe you're the author of this UserScript extension for Chrome?

- https://stackapps.com/questions/3122/stack-exchange-post-editor-performing-basic-corrections-on-posts-automatically

Specifically this line in the extension would seem to be the issue you're mentioning:

```
    SPE_LoadDependentScript('http://files.quickmediasolutions.com/js/jsdiff.min.js', function() {
```

Comment: Hmmm... you're right. I need to find out if anyone is still using it and if so, then embed the jsdiff / livequery scripts in the UserScript to avoid the swarm of requests.

Comment: @NathanOsman - yes I mentioned to everyone here a couple of times this script, which is awesome, BTW, so there are bound to be others here using it too. I noticed that in the last week or so that it's no longer displaying when I edit posts, and hadn't had a chance to look into the issue.

Comment: Can we not just point to a different supplier of that minified .js file? Perhaps Google?

Comment: Ah, okay. My apologies for breaking it then. I recently moved the `files.quickmediasolutions.com` website to another server and not all files were transferred. If there is another site hosting the files, then yes - I will gladly make the update.

Comment: @NathanOsman - what is that file? I can't see what it is/was to know. Nothing like shooting ourselves in the foot, hey?

Comment: There are actually two. The first is `jsmin` and the contents can be found here: http://ejohn.org/files/jsdiff.js The second one is `LiveQuery` and the contents can be found here: https://raw.github.com/brandonaaron/livequery/master/jquery.livequery.js

Comment: Is it available here via Google? https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide

Comment: No, sadly it isn't. I'm probably going to just have to embed them in the UserScript.

Comment: @NathanOsman - that was my next Q. Seems odd though that it keeps redownloading the .js file. I thought it would do it once and then use from a cached copy there after.

Comment: I've created an issue here: https://github.com/nathan-osman/Stack-Exchange-Post-Editor/issues/1 You can track the progress there.

Comment: @NathanOsman - OK, thanks, I'm watching it. In the mean time is there any way I can point to local copies of these files?

Comment: So I finally just decided to restore the files to their original location. I will apply some very heavy caching to these files.